# IF-THEN statement inside a procedure

Tags: postgresql

Why I get the following error:

```
psql:q.sql:22: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 4:     IF id IS NOT NULL THEN
            ^
psql:q.sql:23: WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
COMMIT
```

from:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure(id integer)
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
    IF id IS NOT NULL THEN

    END IF;
END;
```

But if I remove the IF-THEN statement everything is fine.

**My attempt:**
I found the correct syntax by creating a new procedure using DBeaver which actually mentioned [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure()
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
    BEGIN

    END;
$procedure$
```

Now the problem is there is no syntax highlighting for plpgsql :(

Comment: Because you need PL/pgSQL for that. SQL has not IF statement

Comment: How can I use PL/pgSQL?

Comment: Changing SQL to plpgsql does not help.

Comment: After that try reading the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createfunction.html).

Comment: @Dante https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql.html. If you tried to use it already, please [edit] your question to show us your attempt and include the error message you got